# Differentiation of Vector Norm Cubed

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I have a function of the form

$$
f(\mathbb{x}) = w \cdot || \mathbb{x}-m ||^3 
$$

where $w,m$ are constants. Would the following differentiation be correct?

$$
\frac{\partial f(\mathbb{x})}{\partial x} = 3 \cdot 2 \cdot w ||x-m||^2 (x-m)
$$

since

$$
||x-m_1|| = (x-m)^T (x-m)
$$

and the derivative of that is $2 (x-m)$.

Thanks,

Comment: I think there's a minor problem with the formulation $$ ||x - m|| = (x - m)^T (x - m) $$ It should be $$ ||x - m||^2 = (x - m)^T (x - m) $$

Comment: Ah right. How about the rest? When cube is part of the picture is the derivative correct?

Comment: The end answer should look something like $3 * || x - m || * w_{1}  \cdot (x - m)$

Comment: Yes your answer looks good, if I only use $||x||^3$ which is $(x_1^2 + ... + x_n^2)^{3/2}$ the derivative of that $3/2 (x^T x)^{1/2} \cdot 2x = 3 ||x|| \cdot x$

Comment: Maybe it's a stupid question, but shouldn't the derivative of a scalar with respect to a $3\times 1$ vector be a $1\times3$ vector ? If that's the case, $3 * || x-m || w (x-m)$ is a $3\times 1$ vector, so there's a problem. Should it be $3 * || x-m || w (x-m)^T$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For typing convenience, define a new vector
$$\eqalign{
z &= (x-m) \quad\implies\quad dz &= dx \\
}$$
and treat the length $(\lambda)$ as its own variable
$$\eqalign{
\lambda &= \|z\| \\
\lambda^2 &= z^Tz \\
2\lambda\,d\lambda &= 2z^Tdz \quad\implies\quad
\lambda\,d\lambda &= z^Tdx \\
}$$
Now write the function in terms of these new variables.

Then calculate its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
f &= \omega\lambda^3 \\
df &= \omega\,d\lambda^3 = 3\omega\lambda^2\,d\lambda = 3\omega\lambda\,z^Tdx \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &= 3\omega\lambda z
   \;=\; 3\omega\,\left\|x-m\right\|(x-m) \\
}$$